js reg exp помочь дописать регулярку
мне нужно написать следующую регулярку
формат ввода такой
> name:
ATGC

то есть сначала пишем этот знак >, далее пробел, далее имя из любых буковок, далее двоеточие, перенос строки и дальше уже последовательность из таких букв (ATGC),
причем такой формат должен повторяться, то есть я могу в таком формате написать сколь угодно последовательность
> name:
ATGC
> name2:
ATCGC
> name3:
TAATGC

Я написал такую регулярку
!/^(> )+[A-Za-z0-9-]+:+\n+[ATCGatcg]{1,}$/

она работает, но только с одной последовательностью, хотя я вроде указываю кватификатор {1,}, но это не помогает
я пишу это
> name:
ATGC

и все ок, если начинаю писать еще одну последовательность и дописываю её до конца, то ошибка
в общем нужно помочь поставить правильно квантификатор, чтобы я мог писать так:
> name:
ATGC
> name2:
ATGC
> name3:
ATGC

но это естестна не все
поле должно правильно отрабатывтаь если мы записали в таком формате
> name:
ATGC

и в таком
ATCGATAGCATGCTACTGAC

это тоже уже есть, это делается просто [ATCGatcg]
то есть уже без имени и без ">"
при этом регулярка должна так работать, чтобы я мог ввести либо одно либо другое, но не вместе
то есть это допустимо
> name:
ATGC
> name:
ATGC

отдельно это тоже допустимо
ATCGATAGCATGCTACTGAC

а вот если вместе
ATCGATAGCATGCTACTGAC
> name:
ATGC

то уже ошибка, мне кажется это самое сложное
крч я сделаль вот так, работает как надо, но меня смущают эти if-ы хотелос ьбы в одно регулярку все сделать(
  if (
    /^(> [-A-Za-z0-9]+:\r?\n[ATCGatcg]+($|\r?\n))+$/.test(e.target.value)
  ) {
    setError(false);
  } else if (/^[ATGCatgc]+$/.test(e.target.value)) {
    setError(false);
  } else {
    setError(true);
  }




var s = `> name:
ATGC
> name2:
ATGC
> name3:
ATGC`

console.log(/^(> [-A-Za-z0-9]+:\r?\n[ATCGatcg]+($|\r?\n))+$/.test(s));




но хотелось бы чтобы просто ACTGATCCTGA тоже работал



var strs = [
`ACTGATCCTGA`
,
`> name:
ATGC
> name2:
ATGC
> name3:
ATGC`
,
`ACTGATCCTGA
> name:
ATGC`
]

for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s + '\n' +
    /^((> [-A-Za-z0-9]+:\r?\n[ATCGatcg]+($|\r?\n))+|[ATCGatcg]+)$/.test(s)
  );
}
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }




итак, это уже хорошо такой формат работает > name2:
ATGC

name3:
ATGC` но хотелось бы чтобы просто ACTGATCCTGA тоже работал, я подумал что нужно добавить | [ACTGactg] но нет, может будут мысли как это добавить?


в общем нужно что-то вроде такого, но объединить это вместе         !/^(> [-A-Za-z0-9]+:\r?\n[ATCGatcg]+($|\r?\n))+$/.test(e.target.value) |
!/^[ATGCatgc]+$/.test(e.target.value)

внизу дописал то что получилось

@АлексейМелентьев, обновил ответ.

@АлексейМелентьев, перечитал вопрос и ещё раз обновил.
